# Donation list - code issue? There is something wrong in the code

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

When people donate more than once in the page, it only shows their recent donation and not their total donations (in the donations list). For example if I donate $5 now and I will donate $10 later, It will only show $10 and not $5. That's the website: gesher-jds.org/giving-tuesday

How do I fix it?

```
<div class="donors_info">
    <div class="totalenteries"></div>
    <?php
        $valueid = 2727;
        //Get donors based on forms IDs (can be single or multiple forms)
        if(function_exists('give_get_payments')) {
            $args = array(
                'give_forms' => $valueid,
                'number' => -1,
            );
            $donations = give_get_payments( $args );

            echo "<table id='dtab'>";
            echo "<thead>";
            echo "<th align='center'>" . 'Name' . "</th>";
            echo "<th align='center'>" . 'Amount' . "</th>";
            echo "</thead>";
            echo "<tbody>";
            $donors = array();
            foreach($donations as $donation) {                              
                //Now get donor information from this donation ("customer" aka "donor")
                $customer_id = give_get_payment_customer_id( $donation->ID );
                $customers    = new Give_Customer( $customer_id );

                $nameis = $customers->name;
                if (in_array($nameis, $donors)) {} else {   
                    $amt = get_post_meta($donation->ID,'_give_payment_total',true) + 0;         
                    echo "<tr class='select'>";
                    echo "<td align='left'>" . $nameis . "</td>";
                    echo "<td align='center'>" . $purchaseis = "$" . $amt . "</td>";
                    echo "</tr>";
                    $donors[] = $nameis;
                }
            }
            echo "</tbody>";
            echo "</table>";
        }
    ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$amt = get_post_meta($donation->ID,'_give_payment_total',true)
```

"true" returns only the first value for the specified meta key & "false" will give you an array of meta-values. You can iterate the returned array with foreach.

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/

edit:

Yes, you need to change it to false and then you get an array of values. Now you only get a single value.

then iterate the array:

```
$amt = get_post_meta($donation->ID,'_give_payment_total',false);
foreach ($amt as as $key => $value) { 
    echo "<tr class='select'>";
    echo "<td align='left'>" . $nameis . "</td>";
    echo "<td align='center'>" . $purchaseis = "$" . $value . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
```

Code is unchecked, but this ist the way to go. Some information about foreach:

https://www.php.net/manual/de/control-structures.foreach.php

edit 2:
If you want to show all donations in one row:

```
<div class="donors_info">
<div class="totalenteries"></div>
<?php
    $valueid = 2727;
    //Get donors based on forms IDs (can be single or multiple forms)
    if(function_exists('give_get_payments')) {
        $args = array(
            'give_forms' => $valueid,
            'number' => -1,
        );
        $donations = give_get_payments( $args );

        echo "<table id='dtab'>";
        echo "<thead>";
        echo "<th align='center'>" . 'Name' . "</th>";
        echo "<th align='center'>" . 'Amount' . "</th>";
        echo "</thead>";
        echo "<tbody>";
        $donors = array();
        $dtmp=array(); //tmp array
        foreach($donations as $donation) {
            //Now get donor information from this donation ("customer" aka "donor")
            $customer_id = give_get_payment_customer_id( $donation->ID );
            $customers  = new Give_Customer( $customer_id );
            $nameis = $customers->name;

            $amt = get_post_meta($donation->ID,'_give_payment_total',false);
            $donationAll = 0;
            foreach ($amt as $key => $value) { 
                $donationAll = $donationAll + $value;
            }
            //Write a tmp array with name as key and donation as value
            if(array_key_exists($nameis,$dtmp)) {
                //name already exists -> add donation value
                $dtmp[$nameis] = $dtmp[$nameis] + $donationAll;
            } else {
                //name is not in the array -> new array: key name -> donation
                $dtmp[$nameis] = $donationAll;
            }

            $donors[] = $nameis;
        }

        foreach ($dtmp as $key => $value) {
            //iterate the tmp array
            echo "<tr class='select'>";
            echo "<td align='left'>" . $key . "</td>";
            echo "<td align='center'>" . $purchaseis = "$" . $value . "</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
        }

        echo "</tbody>";
        echo "</table>";
    }   
?>
</div>
```

Code is unchecked.

Regards Tom

Comment: Hi Tom, Thanks for the answer. What does it mean? What do I need to change? Do I need to change it to false?

Comment: So if I want that it will count all the donations of one person and not the recent one, I need to change it?

Comment: Yes, you need to change it to false and then you get an array of values (all donation values) back. Now you only get a single value.

then you can iterate the array with

Comment: So will I see a different total? For example now, when I donate $5 and later I will donate $10, I will only see the $10. So If I change it to false, It will show $15?

Comment: I don't want to show $10 and $5 separably, but $15 total.

Comment: I could not edit my comment any more and updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks Tom! So the second one will show $15 and the first one will $5 and $10 separably?

Comment: I tried to change it to false, but then the whole design of the page looked pretty bad. Do you know why?

Comment: Yes, you need to edit your code like in the "edit 2" example on my updated answer. It looks bad because the variable you get in return is an array of data and not a single value.

Comment: I used your edit 2 example, but the design looked pretty bad as well. Is there a way not to change the design? The design looked broken with an error message.

Comment: Any ideas what I should do?

Comment: I updated the edit 2 - that "+0" would not work with an array. You can try this and and then tell me the error message if one shows up.

Comment: There is no error message which is good and it does show all the donations, but I did want that it will show all the donations of the same person only once. For example It shows that Jennifer donated $10 and $10, but I want that it will show $20 instead of separate donations. I want it to show the total. Take a look now: gesher-jds.org/giving-tuesday  I do I make it happen?

Comment: Any ideas? Thanks for the help!

Comment: Sometimes it is hard to imagine how the code is going to work without having the whole picture. And I can`t test it properly, but I updated the "edit 2" and you can try this if it works. Tell me if there are php or any other errors showing up.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much!!

Comment: You are welcome! If it works then accept the answer, please.

Comment: Done! Thank you so much!